# Hanging Searches, Listings

Tags: joomla, search, search-results, quicksearch

I'm trying to test CiviCRM to see if it'll be right for our organization, but try as I might, I just can't get contact searches (either through the quicksearch or profile -> frontend) to return any results. In fact, they just hang, and after a great while (20+ minutes?) will finally timeout.

I've removed all options from search settings, tried appending "force=1" to URLs, turned off SEF entirely, played with Joomla menu link types, all to no avail. The profile search page will load fine, but entering any (or no) data will cause a total hang and never returns. Similarly, hitting "Back to listings" from a contact view, actually clicking on any data in contact view, or running a quick contact search in administration backend all result in a load forever loop.

My error logs make mention of some client denied access errors, so I made my htaccess file allow all, but that didn't seem to have any effect (other than stopping the errors).

Does anyone happen to have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a problem on your install/instance, perhaps a host issue.

If you are evaluating CiviCRM, you may first want to try the [Joomla Demo](https://civicrm.org/demo) and/or create a sandbox to test on.

Once you have done the evaluation you can look in to why your instance is giving you problems.